# C++ Insertion operator overload (<<)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

I'm working through an assignment in which I must overload the insertion operator to take a Node object. I've created the operator overload function outside the class definition, but inside the node.h file. Everything compiles fine, but the overloaded operator is not called, instead I get simple the address of the object.

I'm prohibited from modifying the calling code, so any changes must be to the operator overload.

My code as it stands right now:

```
/** OPERATOR << ***********************************/
template<class T>
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Node <T> *& pHead)
{
    out << "INCOMPLETE";
    return out;
}
```

Right now, I just want to ensure the overloaded operator is called. I'll fix the output code once I know I'm calling the right operator.

The calling code:

```
// create
Node <char> * n = NULL;

// code modifying n

// display
cout << "\t{ " << n << " }\n";
```

Comment: `cout <<  *n;` would be a easier solution

Comment: That's true, but as stated, I am unable to modify the calling code.

Comment: sorry, miss that part.

Comment: not very sure, maybe remove the & in `const Node <T> *&` will work, or you can also provide a non-const version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the parameter `pHead`'s type is a reference to non-const, `const Node<T>*` is a non-const pointer to const, the argument `n`'s type is `Node<T>*` (i.e. a non-const pointer to non-const). Their type doesn't match, `Node<T>*` need to be converted to `const Node<T>*`, which is a temporary and can't be bound to  reference to non-const.

In short, you can't bind a reference to non-const to an object with different type.

But reference to const could be bound to temporary, so you can change the parameter type to reference to const:

```
template<class T>
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Node <T> * const & pHead)
//                                                                      ~~~~~
```

Or change it to passed-by-value, `Node<T>*` will be implicitly converted to `const Node<T>*` when passing as argument. (Passing pointer by reference to const doesn't make much sense.)

```
template<class T>
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Node <T> * pHead)
```

At last, overloading `operator<<` with pointer type looks weird. The most common form with user-defined type would be:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Node <T> & pHead)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the details of using const and the reference types. The last code block is where I started, but I was informed by the class moderator that it needed to take a pointer. The first code block you posted works great (for this assignment anyway.) I'll keep you best-practice tips in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the inserter takes a parameter of type `const Node<T>*`, but it's called with an argument of type `Node<T>*`; there is no conversion from `T*` to `const T*`. So the "fix" is to remove the `const` from the stream inserter.

But, as hinted at in a comment, having an inserter that takes a pointer to a type is a bad idea. It should take a `const Node<T>&`, like all the other inserters in the world. I gather that this is a constraint imposed by an assignment; if so, it's idiotic. You're being taught badly.

Comment: You are right about this being a constraint of the class. The course has us build a Node class, and some independent functions. The following week, we take the Node class, and these functions, and roll them up into the Doubly Linked List class. So far (5 weeks) all other data structures have used the common method you indicated. I believe this week is different because the Node class is not a complete Abstract Data Type.