# Trying to overload insertion operator for template class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I've looked at similar questions, but no one asking a similar question seemed to be experiencing quite the same problem as I am. I'm trying to overload operator<< for a binary tree node. Here's my code:

```
template <class T>
class BinaryNode
{
public:

    //Constructors
    BinaryNode() : pLeft(NULL), pRight(NULL), pParent(NULL) {}
    BinaryNode(T contents) : data(contents), pLeft(NULL), pRight(NULL), pParent(NULL) {}

    // return size (i.e. number of nodes in tree)
    int size() const
    {
            return 1 +
               (pLeft== NULL? 0 : pLeft->size()) +
               (pRight == NULL ? 0 : pRight->size());
    }

    // add a node the left/right
    void addLeft (BinaryNode <T> * pNode);
    void addRight(BinaryNode <T> * pNode);

    // create a node and add it to the left/right
    void addLeft (const T & t) throw (const char *);
    void addRight(const T & t) throw (const char *);

    // since no validation is done, everything is public
    BinaryNode <T> * pLeft;
    BinaryNode <T> * pRight;
    BinaryNode <T> * pParent;

    // the data of unknown type: cannot validate so is public
    T data;
};
```

And the overloaded operator, later in the same file:

EDIT: Fixed the problem where I was incorrectly referencing member variables.

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BinaryNode<T>*& rhs)
{
    if (!rhs)
        return out;
    if (rhs->pLeft)
        out << rhs->pLeft;
    out << rhs->data << ' ';
    if (rhs->pRight)
        out << rhs->pRight;
    return out;
}
```

I'm getting a huge host of errors, which all disappear if I comment out the overloaded operator. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
The errors, if you care to sift through them, are:

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    
Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition  
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'filename'  
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'const'   
Error   C2050   switch expression not integral  
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'word': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'tree': undeclared identifier   
Error   C3861   'testSimple': identifier not found  
Error   C3861   'testMerge': identifier not found   
Error   C3861   'testDisplay': identifier not found 
Error   C3861   'testAdd': identifier not found 
Error   C2065   'T': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'string': undeclared identifier 
Error   C2065   'out': undeclared identifier    
Error   C2065   'ostream': undeclared identifier    
Error   C3861   'huffman': identifier not found
Error   C2065   'fileName': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'fileName': undeclared identifier
Error   C2065   'fileName': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'fileName': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'choice': undeclared identifier 
Error   C2065   'choice': undeclared identifier 
Error   C2923   'BinaryNode': 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
```

Comment: "I'm getting a huge host of errors" Like what?

Comment: In the `operator<<` function, what is the *type* of `rhs`? Is it not a *pointer*? How do you access members of *pointers to structures*?

Comment: Are you using `using namespace std`? Because if you don't you should use `std::` in the overload: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out.....` This compiles fine for me

Comment: @KillzoneKid that fixed all the comile errors, but now the overloaded function is just never called  - it simply prints out the pointer in hex.

Comment: `>>it simply prints out the pointer in hex`. You need to provide verifiable example for that

Comment: Found a fix for that in another question - if anyone's having a similar issue in the future, go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179620/c-insertion-operator-overload

Answer (score 0):

Your operator signature is wrong, it should take a reference to object, not a reference to pointer to object:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BinaryNode<T> & rhs)
```

And you should update operator body accordingly.